# USB IDE HDD in Ubuntu 22.04 is not working

Tags: usb, hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, ide

I have have some IDE disks very old stuff,
I would like to backup all data to a newer HDD or SSD, so I buy an USB IDE adapter to do the work.

When I plug the HDD on the adapter the SO only recognize the USB and not the HDD.

About the HDD:

- **Seagate ST34321A 4GB**, RAW file system (Possible FAT16), origin unknown. There is a clicking noise when i try to read the end of the disk during IMG backup whit TestDisk.
  TestDisk Failed to create image, finished with errors.

**sudo lsblk**

[image]

...Trying now ddrescue...

Is IDE drives too old and Ubuntu, so it does not recognize the anymore?
Is something not enabled on the kernel?
Some HDD got /dev/sdX

I followed this [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nclwd.png)

ddrescue got successful in copying the data

```
sudo ddrescue -d /dev/sdX backup.img backup.logfile

and

sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdX backup.img backup.logfile
```

Now I need to figure out how to read/recover the data from the .img images. Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: What format are the old disks? What sort of filesystem do they have? What dystem did they come from?

Comment: Seagate ST34321A 4GB, RAW file system (Possible FAT16), origin unknown. There is a clicking noise when i try to read the end of the disk during IMG backup whit TestDisk.

Comment: What does `sudo lsblk` show when the disk is attached?

Comment: I updated the original post

Comment: **There is a clicking noise**", this is a telltale sign of a physically broken hard drive. The arm of the read/write head is misaligned and hitting something. It will never read anything again unless the drive is opened and the arm is replaced.

Comment: These drives are fragile. A drop or a hard knock may cause the read head to get dislodged or the platter (disks) to crack.